# Is the set of separable quantum states closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

Let $\mathcal H,\mathcal H'$ be Hilbert spaces (not necessarily separable).

A "separable state" is a trace-class operator of the form $\sum_i \rho_i\otimes\rho_i'$ where $\rho_i,\rho_i'$ are positive trace-class operators over $\mathcal H,\mathcal H'$, respectively. (Convergence of the sum is with respect to the trace norm. $\otimes$ represents the tensor product.)

Is the set of separable states closed with respect to the trace norm?

Comment: I guess the sum is meant to converge in the space of trace class operators acting on the Hilbert space $\mathcal H \otimes \mathcal H'$ (this being the Hilbert space tensor product)?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is negative if we believe [1] (which comes without proofs, unfortunately):

[1] defines the set of separable states as the convex closure of $\{\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i\otimes\tau_i\}$. I will call that set $S$. The set as defined in the original question I call $T$. Then $T\subseteq S$, and $T=S$ iff the answer is yes (i.e., iff $T$ is closed).

[1] shows that there is a $\rho\in S$ such that $\rho$ cannot be represented as a Bochner integral $\int\psi\psi^*\otimes\phi\phi^* \pi(d(\psi,\phi))$ for an atomic measure $\pi$. ($\rho$ is not "countably decomposable" in their language.)

Any $\rho\in T$ can be represented as such an integral with a discrete and hence atomic measure $\pi$. Thus $T\subsetneq S$.

---

On the positive side, if we define $T':=\{\int\psi\psi^*\otimes\phi\phi^* \pi(d(\psi,\phi))\}$ for probability measures $\pi$, then [1] shows $S=T'$. In particular, $T'$ is closed. So, in the spirit of the original question, the set of infinite convex combinations of $\sigma_i\otimes\tau_i$ is closed, only the notion of 
"infinite convex combination" must be changed: Not infinite sums, but integrals.

---

[1] *Werner, R. F.; Kholevo, A. S.; Shirokov, M. E.*, [**On the concept of entanglement in Hilbert spaces.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/RM2005v060n02ABEH000830), Russ. Math. Surv. 60, No. 2, 359-360 (2005); translation from Usp. Mat. Nauk 60, No. 2, 153-154 (2005). [ZBL1098.47019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1098.47019).

Comment: It's worth noting that while there are not proofs, the counter-example is Theorem 2 which is very concrete and explicit.

Answer (score 7):

**[There are difficulties with this proof, see the comments]**

Yes, it's closed. Here's a soft proof (which requires a bit of C*-theory).

Let $A$ be a (not necessarily unital) C*-algebra and 
${\mathcal Q}(A)\subset A^*$ denotes the quasi-state space (i.e., the space of 
positive linear functional of norm $\le1$), which is compact in the weak*-topology. 
I claim that if $\Omega\subset {\mathcal Q}(A)$ is weak*-closed, then 
$$\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n : \phi_n\in\Omega,\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|\phi_n\|\le1\}\subset {\mathcal Q}(A)$$ 
is also weak*-closed. 
Specialize this to $A=K({\mathcal H}\otimes{\mathcal H}')$ and 
$\Omega={\mathcal Q}(K({\mathcal H}))\times{\mathcal Q}(K({\mathcal H}'))$.

Proof of Claim: 
Let $\tilde{A}\subset\ell_\infty({\mathbb N},A)$ denote the C*-algebra 
of the norm-convergent sequences in $A$. 
Then $\tilde{A}$ is an extension of $A$ by $c_0({\mathbb N},A)$. 
Hence any $\phi\in {\mathcal Q}(\tilde{A})$ is of the form $\phi=(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_\infty)$, 
$$\tilde{A}\ni a=(a_n)_n \mapsto (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_n(a_n)) + \phi_\infty(\lim_n a_n) \in{\mathbb C},$$
where $\phi_n\in {\mathcal Q}(A)$ satisfy $\|\phi\|=(\sum_n\|\phi_n\|)+\|\phi_\infty\|\le1$. 
It is not difficult to see that 
$$\tilde{\Omega}:=\{ \phi\in {\mathcal Q}(\tilde{A}) : \phi_n\in\Omega,\ n=1,\ldots,\infty\}$$ 
is weak*-closed. 
Thus its restriction to $A\subset\tilde{A}$ (diagonal embedding) is also weak*-closed (weak*-compact).
This restriction is what we were looking after.

Comment: I have some questions (I am not an expert in C*-algebras). First, just to make sure: The weak*-topology is the topology of pointwise convergence in this context, and compactness of $\cal Q(A)$ is the Banach–Alaoglu theorem? Second, when you say "its restriction to $A\subseteq\tilde A$", you mean the set $e(\tilde\Omega)$ where $e(\phi):=\phi|A$ for $\phi\in \cal Q(\tilde A)$? Then I understand the proof of the claim up to the last step: Why is that restriction weak*-closed?

Comment: And finally: I do not understand the notation $\cal Q(K(\cal H))\times\cal Q(K(\cal H'))$ (I don't know how pairs of functionals are interpreted as functionals), but I assume I should set $\Omega:=\{\phi:\phi(A):=\operatorname{tr}(\sigma\otimes\tau)A, 0\leq\sigma,\tau\leq 1\}$ where $\sigma,\tau$ are trace class and $A$ is compact. I don't know how to show that $\Omega$ is weak*-closed in that case.

Comment: @Dominique Unruh: Yes to the first. For the second, the restriction map is weak*-continuous and so it preserves weak*-compactness. Finally, $\Omega$ is indeed what you wrote. If $\phi_i=\sigma_i\otimes\tau_i$ converges weak* (w.r.t. $K({\mathcal H}\otimes{\mathcal H}')$), then by compactness (Banach--Alaoglu), we may find a subnet for which both $\sigma_i$ and $\tau_i$ converge weak* to, say, $\sigma$ and $\tau$. Then $\phi_i$ converges to $\sigma\otimes\tau$ on the algebraic tensor product $K({\mathcal H})\otimes K({\mathcal H}')$, but since $\phi_i$ is uniformly bounded, this is enough.

Comment: Or use weak*-continuity of ${\mathcal Q}(K({\mathcal H}))\times{\mathcal Q}(K({\mathcal H}'))\to{\mathcal Q}(K({\mathcal H}\otimes{\mathcal H}'))$ to obtain weak*-compactness of the image.

Comment: I got all the steps now, thank you. (Except for the continuity of $\cal Q(K(\cal H))\times \cal Q(K(\cal H'))\to\cal Q (K(\cal H\otimes\cal H '))$ since am not even sure what that function is. I don't see an isomorphism between those two spaces. But fortunately, I can just use the argument from you comment before, so I am good.)

Comment: For completeness, let me add two things that are missing w.r.t. my original question: I was interested in $\sum_i\sigma_i\otimes\tau_i$ where $i$ ranges over a possibly uncountable set. But using the fact that any uncountable sum of positive trace-class operators must have co-countably many zeroes, that case follows from your proof. Furthermore, "separable states" in my definition can have trace $>1$. That case can be covered by derived as a corollary from your proof using that every neighborhood of separable states falls into a (scaled) version of the set of separable states you considered.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh If $A,B$ are C*-algebras, and we use $A \otimes B$ for the maximal C* tensor product, the map $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathcal{Q}}\Q(A) \times \Q(B) \rightarrow \Q(A \otimes B)$ is defined by $(\phi \otimes \psi)(a \otimes b) = \phi(a) \psi(b)$ and extending by linearity and continuity (though proving positivity is easier by tensoring GNS representations). Then compose this with the iso $\newcommand{\H}{\mathcal{H}}K(\H) \otimes K(\H') \cong K(\H \otimes \H')$. In this special case it might be simpler to identify $\Q(K(\H))$ with density matrices of trace $\leq 1$ and work that way.

Comment: I do not see how to prove that $\tilde\Omega$ is weak$^*$-closed, without already knowing that I can sum absolutely summable sequences in $\Omega$ without leaving $\Omega$.  The problem I have is that if $(\phi^{(i)})$ is a net in $\tilde Q$ converging to $\phi$ say, then how can I show that $\phi_\infty \in \Omega$?  (That $\phi_n\in\Omega$ for $n<\infty$ is clear.)

Comment: @Matthew Daws: You are right. $\phi\mapsto\phi_\infty$ is not weak*-continuous. My proof seems to fall apart.

Comment: What is wrong with this proof of $\tilde\Omega$ weak*-closed: Fix $\tilde\Omega\ni\phi_n\to\phi$. $\phi_{ni}(a)\to\phi_i(a)$ for $i<\infty$. Also $\sum_i\phi_{ni}(a)+\phi_{n\infty}(a)=\phi_n(a')\to\phi(a')=\sum_i\phi_{i}(a)+\phi_{\infty}(a)$ where $a'=a,a,\dots$. Together $\phi_{n\infty}(a)\to\phi_\infty(a)$. Then $\Omega\ni\phi_{n\infty}\to\phi_\infty$. Since $\Omega$ is closed, $\phi_\infty(a)\in\Omega$.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh  The problem is that this argument implicitly swaps the processes of taking the infinite sum over $i$ and taking the limit in $n$.  You can't do that.

Comment: True. I had thought I can apply Tannery's theorem (since the sums were absolutely convergent in $\mathbb C$), but I overlooked the uniform boundedness condition.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer (and I now suspect that the answer is negative), 
but this maybe still useful and in any case too lengthy for a comment. 
Assume that $\mathcal H$ and ${\mathcal H}'$ are separable.
The norm-closed convex hull of 
$$\Omega=\{ \phi\otimes\psi : 0\le\phi, \, \|\phi\|\le 1,\,0\le\psi,\, \|\psi\|\le1\}$$
is 
$$\tilde{\Omega}:=\{ \int_{\mathbb R} f(t) \, dt : f\in L^1({\mathbb R},\Omega),\, \|f\|\le 1\}.$$
Note that the weak*-measurability and norm-measurability for $f$ coincide 
by separability assumption. 
In particular, $\tilde{\Omega}$ is contained in the norm convex hull of $\Omega$. 
I claim $\tilde{\Omega}$ is weak*-closed. 
Let's equip $\Omega$ with the weak*-topology 
coming from $K({\mathcal H}\otimes{\mathcal H}')$, which makes 
$\Omega$ compact. 
Then, the space $\mathrm{Prob}(\Omega)$ of Radon probability measures is 
compact w.r.t. the weak* topology induced by $C(\Omega)$.
It follows that 
$$\{\int_\Omega \omega \, d\mu(\omega) : \mu\in \mathrm{Prob}(\Omega)\}.$$
is weak*-compact and so it is the weak*-closed convex hull of $\Omega$. 
As $L^1(\Omega,\mu)\hookrightarrow L^1({\mathbb R},\mathrm{Leb})$, 
we conclude that $\tilde{\Omega}$ is the weak*-closed convex hull of $\Omega$.